# What is the most reliable way to test old capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, test

I have a few old electrolytic capacitors from an old system that have not been used in many years.
I was thinking I might test them.

What is the best way to reliably test these old caps?

Comment: Why bother testing them if they are both electrolytic and many years old?

Comment: I guess it is something I would like to know how to do, also hard to find replacement caps for this particular system.

Comment: Standard DMMs have provisions for testing capacitors. It would be wise to not reuse them though. Read [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/older-electrolytic-capacitor-testing.966712/) for instance.

Answer (score 2):

By using the following specialized meters, in combination:

1. [Capacitor ESR Meter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=capacitor+ESR+meter).  These measure the [Equivalent-Series-Resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) (and usually report the capacitance also.) ESR is the internal resistance in series with the cap.  Ideally, this should be 0Ω but all caps have some resistance.  As this resistance increases due to age, certain circuits (which need that ESR to be low) can be affected.  Some capacitor types do not suffer from this issue, such as mylar, polypropylene, ceramic, etc.  Mostly ESR affects electrolytics.
2. [Capacitor Leakage Meter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=capacitor+leakage).  This tests how insulative the capacitor is.  Old (electrolytic, paper, wax) caps tend to "get leaky" as they age, which is to say, form a parallel resistance.  Depending on the voltage and role, this could cause a circuit not to work or the cap to even get too hot and explode.  In general, paper and wax capacitors are no longer used and if found, are assumed leaky and changed on-sight.

Then for electrolytic caps which have not been used in more than a year or two, it is recommended to "re-form" them.  [Electrolytic Capacitor Reforming](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=electrolytic+reforming) is the process of slowly raising the voltage across an old capacitor (instead of just flipping the power switch) so that the the internal components have time to re-form their chemical state.  Without reforming, electrolytics run the risk of shorting and could fail (catastrophically, in the case of high-voltage electrolytics.)

Comment: Can a surface resistivity meter be used as well?

Comment: Possibly, if it can measure giga-Ohms with a voltage that is less than the capacitor rating.   [Mr. Carlson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhovRIM5xAo) has created a nice capacitor leakage detector.